# Notepad regex multiplying operator

Tags: regex, notepad++, operator-keyword, multiplication

How to use multiplying operator in Notepad++ by specifying how many copies it applies to?
The manual tells (and as far as I know it is standard) to use `{n}`. But this doesn't work.
For example, if I have a file containing text 123123. Then `\d{2}` returns "Can't find the text ", but `\d\d` works as expected.
This is very basic and trivial, am I missing something?

Comment: `\d{2}` works for me. Have you rechecked the other search-options like `Wrap around`?

Comment: I've checked `Wrap around` (and nothing else), Search mode is also `Regular expression`.

Comment: @user1335014 The Regex engine in Notepad++ changed recently. How old is your version?

Comment: @AdamHawkes It was v5 something, the problem was fixed after updating.

Comment: Is the regex plugin finally working again? I don't even see it available as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It must have been v5 bug.

In the current Notepad++ version 6.9.2, `\d{2}` works correctly.